# HTACCESS rewrite not working for non WP directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have WordPress installed in the root folder of my domain `example.com` and have another directory which has custom PHP code `example.com/control/`.

With no WordPress installation my `.htaccess` file was redirecting `/control/show.php?id=2` as `/control/2/` and working perfectly fine but once I have installed WP in root it's no longer working.

ROOT `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

`/control/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^control/([^/]*)$ /control/show.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Please, help me understand the error and how can I make it work.

Comment: `RewriteBase /`  ??

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the reply, can you guide me what's with ReWriteBase / and this need correction in root file and subdirectory folder htaccess?

Comment: IMO, it's very rare to ever need to use `RewriteBase`

Comment: @phil Do you recommend removing that from both and try it?

Comment: Removed, Still Not Working :(

Answer (score 1):

> `control/.htaccess`
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^control/([^/]*)$ /control/show.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

This doesn't work in the `/control/.htaccess` file because the `RewriteRule` directive is written as if it is in the `.htaccess` file in the document root.

In `.htaccess` the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path less the directory-prefix (that lead to the `.htaccess` file). In other words, it matches against `2/`, not `control/2/`. That is the reason why the above directive is not working.

Not an error, but you don't need to explicitly state the `/control/` subdirectory in the *substitution* either, as this will be prefixed automatically, providing you use a relative path substitution. Likewise, you don't need the `RewriteBase` directive either (it's arguably set incorrectly anyway in this context).

So, the above should be written like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ show.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `NC` flag is also superfluous in this example.

You should be as specific as possible in your regex. If the "id" is always *digits* (as in your example) then modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to match only digits: `^(\d*)$`
(0 or more digits).

Answer (score 0):

***You don't need to create a control .htaccess***

```
RewriteRule ^control/([^/]*)$ /control/show.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

*Add the above code before # BEGIN WordPress in the wordpress htaccess file.*

Hope this might help.

Comment: Whilst a separate `.htaccess` file in the `/control` subdirectory is not necessarily required, it might still be desirable to keep this entirely separate from the WordPress config.